# Why does the function provided by Context.Provider not change the value from the same context?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to write a simple AuthProvider. For this I have context:

```
type ContextType = {
    auth: string
    setAuth: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>
}  
const AuthContext = createContext({} as ContextType)
```

And actually the Provider itself

```
type Props = {
    children: ReactNode
}

export function AuthProvider({children}: Props):JSX.Element {
   const [auth, setAuth] = useState<string>("") 
   const value = useMemo(() => ({
        auth, setAuth
   }), [auth]);
  
   console.log("inside - ",auth)
   return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
   )
}
  
export function useAuth(): ContextType {
    return useContext(AuthContext)
}
```

And the problem is that `saveAuth` does not change the value. That is, when I receive a token, I try to save it :

```
 const { auth,setAuth } = useAuth();
const response = await getToken(data);
if (response) {
    const accessToken = response.access
    saveAuth(accessToken)
}
```

And now inside Requier:

```
const RequierAuth = () => {
    const { auth } = useContext(AuthContext) as AuthContextType;
    const location = useLocation();
    console.log("require : ", auth)
    return (
        auth != undefined && auth !== ""?<Outlet/> : <Navigate to = "/auth" state = {{from:location}} replace />
    );

}
```

the value is always default, i.e. `""`.Although the token that I receive and save is correct .What is the error with this function ?

I may be wrong, but something is wrong with Require Auth. I.e. I added the log to:

```
console.log("inside - ",auth)
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
```

And after calling the `setAuth` function, the value changes, now I go to the page protected by `RequireAuth` and the log shows that auth is now empty. I don 't understand why this is so ?

**index**:

```
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
     <BrowserRouter>
     <AuthProvider>
      <App />
     </AuthProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**app**

```
<div className="App">
      <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
            <Route path="auth" element={<SignInForm />} />
            <Route path="reg" element={<SignUpForm />} />
            <Route element = {<RequierAuth/>}>
                <Route path="home" element={<Home />} />              
            </Route>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have more than one `<AuthProvider />` somewhere?

Comment: You can use `useContext(...)!` instead, with a non-nullable assertion, instead of a lengthy assertion using `as AuthContextType`.

Comment: @Konrad no.Only in index ```<BrowserRouter><AuthProvider><App /></AuthProvider></BrowserRouter>```

Comment: Is `auth` an empty string or `undefined` in the `RequireAuth`?

Comment: @Konrad empty string. log : ```require :```

Comment: Maybe `accessToken` is an empty string

Comment: @Konrad No, I even just used "abc" and the result is the same

Comment: Do you have this project hosted on GitHub or could you reproduce it on codesandbox?

Comment: @Konrad codesandbox added

Comment: Two things: you can use bootstrap links, you must use `NavLink` or `Link` from react router dom. Second, your home link points to `/` but should to `/home`. If you change these it will work fine

Comment: @Konrad Are you sure you reproduced the problem correctly? I changed what you said, but that's not the point here.When submit is executed in ```/auth``` , then in console ```inside - abc``` .That is , auth has been saved , now you can change it to /home in the address itself and return it back to the same page and it will print in the console that auth is empty

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-cartwright-gn12l6?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: @Konrad Thanks you, navigation through the button works. But it is not clear why the same thing does not work if you write the address /home yourself after submit

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code:

PS. If you're not using typescript just remove types declaration :D

```
type Props = {
  children: ReactNode
}
type ContextType = {
  auth: string
  setAuth: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>
  // add here other variables and functions 
  // you want to export with your context
}

const AuthContext = createContext({} as ContextType)

export function AuthProvider({
  children
}: Props):JSX.Element {
  // using string but could be whatever type your auth varable is
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState<string>('') 

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={
        useMemo(() => ({
          auth,
          setAuth,
          // add here other variables/functions exported
          // E.g.: currentTheme, setCurrentTheme
          // loading, setLoading, etc...
        }), [
          auth
          // add here other variables those values changes
          // E.g.: currentTheme, loading, etc...
        ])
      }
    >
    ...
    {children}
    ...
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}

export function useAuth(): ContextType {
  return useContext(AuthContext)
}
```

Now you need to use the provider somewhere else above all components that you want to access the context data.

E.g.:

```
// index.tsx
import {AuthProvider} from '..../auth.tsx'

....

return (
  <AuthProvider>
    <MyAppComponent />
  </AuthProvider>
)
```

Then inside `MyAppComponent` you just need to call the `useAuth` function to access all exported variables and functions

E.g.:

```
import {useAuth} from '..../auth.tsx'

...

const {
  auth,
  setAuth
} = useAuth()

...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. ```auth``` is still empty inside ```RequierAuth```. I tried to put a non-empty string as the initial value and everything works.That is, the function from ```useState``` for some reason does not update the string

Comment: Are you consumming your provider? you must place your child component (the component you want to have access to auth data) inside the AuthProvider component.

Comment: Also try using arrow function when setting your variables with useState. E.g.: `setAuth(() => 'somevalue')` this will make sure your value always changes to the latest setted value, for a better explanation see [this](https://youtu.be/GGo3MVBFr1A?t=177)

Comment: Yes, it seems to me that AuthProvider is placed correctly, I edited my post just in case)

Comment: I've created a working example in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/context-example-6v2h9l?file=/auth.tsx), take a look. Hope it helps :D